# Drag and drop item to trigger event

Tags: jquery, animation, user-interface, drag-and-drop, user-experience

I'm creating a website that contains also a section for downloading an ebook after payment. In order to make a nice user interface i would like to use an icon of the ebook and an icon of a shopping cart and allow the visitor to drag the icon of the ebook into the shopping cart in order to trigger an action that leads to the purchase of the ebook. I heard about the function [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) in Jquery UI  and about the [Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/) javascript library. Can anybody suggest me other ways to achieve this or provide a proof of concept code?

Comment: There is a simply demo on the jQueryUI website. This should give you an idea. http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery ui `draggable/droppable/sortable` functionalities just like here:

{this is the jquery ui shopping-cart basic demo plus ability of drop out item from the shopping cart}

http://jsfiddle.net/RR6z5/1/embedded/result/

Comment: thanks for the answer..i saw this example too..it could be ok but how do i start an event when the item is dragged and dropped into the cart? I'd need a more complete example including this phase.

Comment: See 'drop' callback function of droppable: http://jsfiddle.net/RR6z5/1/ BTW, you should consider to just read documentation...